# Batch script to read specific word from a text file and write to another file

Tags: file, batch-file, text

I need some help on a batch script which has to achieve the following :

1. Placed into the root structure,with # folders
2. Open each subfolder, then read out a specific line from a text file (name of file varies).
3. Create another text file to show "OK" or "NOT OK" based on the presence of the previously searched line.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me a hand.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the "specific line"? Start with `FOR /?` and go from there. `Findstr /?`, `Set /?` and `If /?` will come in handy too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it would be something like this:

- It searches for *.txt files in every folder.
- Read each file for string "This is my line"
- if found, it would write "filename.txt" is OK in D:\FileStatus.txt
- if not found, it would write "filename.txt" is Not OK in
  D:\FileStatus.txt

@echo off

```
Set DirToSearch="D:\MyFolders\"
Set LineToRead="This is my line"

pushd %DirToSearch%
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
    For /F %%l in ('Findstr /L /I %LineToRead% "%%f"') do (
     if %%l equ " " (
        echo File:"%%f" is Not OK >> D:\FileStatus.txt
     ) else (
        echo Line: %%l
        echo File:"%%f" is OK >> D:\FileStatus.txt
     )
)
)

Goto :End

:End
popd
```

Hope it helps.